# cannot display OpenGL texture

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have been trying to use OpenGL to render an image to a screen and in order to learn more about texturing etc., my approach was to do map the image to the texture and then draw it using GL_QUADS. However, all I get is a blank screen.

So, the texture was initialised as follows:

```
class Texture
{
public:
    void init_texture(int rows, int cols);
    void load_texture(const Image * frame);

    GLuint      _texture_obj;

};

void Texture::init_texture(int rows, int cols)
{
    if (_texture_obj) glDeleteTextures(1, &_texture_obj);

    _texture_target = GL_TEXTURE_2D;
    glGenTextures(1, &_texture_obj);

    if (_texture_obj) {
        glBindTexture(_texture_target, _texture_obj);
        glTexImage2D(_texture_target, 0, GL_BGRA, cols, rows, 0, 
                     GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid *)NULL);
        glTexParameterf(_texture_target, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, 
                        GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameterf(_texture_target, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, 
                        GL_LINEAR);
    }
    else {
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not create the OpenGL texture");
    }
}

void Texture::load_texture(const Image *frame)
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture_obj);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, frame->cols(), 
                    frame->rows(), GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                    frame->data());
}
```

The code above initializes and loads the texture.

To display the texture, I use a QOpenGLWidget derived object where the initialization and the paint method looks like this:

```
class GLWidget: public QOpenGLWidget
{
public:
    GLWidget(Image *image);
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    void paintGL();

private:
    Texture texture;
};


void GLWidget::GLWidget(Image * image)
{
   texture.init(image->rows, image->cols);
   texture.load(image);
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();    
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_REPLACE);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture._tex_object);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        // width(), height() gives the component width and height
        glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex2i(0, 0);
        glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex2i(0, this->width());
        glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex2i(this->height(), this->width());
        glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex2i(this->height(), 0);
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

However, this only shows me a blank screen. Is there some viewport that I need to setup? I only started using OpenGL a few days ago, so am quite green in that aspect. I am using qt version 5.4 and OpenGL 4.3 on linux.

Comment: Is `tex_id` a member of `GLWidget`?  How is it populated?  Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Added it to make it more clear. Hope that is ok.

Answer (score 3):

The call

```
glTexImage2D(_texture_target, 0, GL_BGRA, cols, rows, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid *)NULL);
```

is invalid, because `GL_BGRA` is not a valid `internalFormat`. You should use `GL_RGBA` for that. Note that the `internalFormat` just defines the basic data type and the number of channels, the actual layout is totally implementation-specific. The `format` parameter on the other hand tells the GL how to interpret the data in client memory, so formats like `GL_RGBA` and `GL_BGRA` are actually defined.

I'm not really familiar with `QOpenGLWidget`. However, I think that creating your texture in the constructor might be a bad idea, as the GL context might not be available at that point (or at least not made current to the thread). You should move that stuff into `initializeGL()`.

Comment: It is not created actually in the constructor. The actual layout of the code is slightly more complicated and I did it to simplify it.However, I verified that the OPenGLContext is valid (it gets called due to the parent being QOpenGLWidget. However, I will have to wait till the weekend is over to verify if this wrong internal format is indeed the cause as I somehow cannot use ssh to my work computer and have the OpenGL working properly and my home machine is not setup. I will update this thread as soon as I can do some tests on Monday.

Comment: So, I made that change but it still does not render the texture.

Comment: It is totally unclear how your transformations are set up, so nobody can tell where (if at all) on the screen this should appear.

Comment: I figured out the issue. The texture appears if I use normalised coordinates between -1 and 1 and replace glTexCoord2i with glTexCoord2f and glVertex2i with glVertex2f.

Comment: internal format of `GL_BGRA` changed to `GL_RGBA` is exactly what I needed, search `internalFormat` (and see tables shown) for valid internal format specs on [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) docs.  Thanks @derhass :)